# Sorting in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have the below code with a list as:

```
def l = ['a','e','A','x','Z','p','Q']
println(l.sort())
```

Which generates output as:

```
[A, Q, Z, a, e, p, x]
```

Now, I know that this is ASCII based sorting, I just want to get the correct result. What are the possible solutions for this situation? What I want is something like:

```
[A, a, e, p, Q, x, Z]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
['a','e','A','x','Z','p','Q'].sort { it.toLowerCase() }
```

Comment: It worked. What is "it"? I am very new to groovy and going through Groovy Programming book. Thanks for help.

Comment: `it` is default name for the object that was passed as an argument to closure, you can use other name: `['a','e','A','x','Z','p','Q'].sort { elem -> elem.toLowerCase() }`

Comment: Thanks for the help @Opal.

Comment: @saurav, you're welcome. Please accept the answer if you found it useful.

Comment: I will @Opal. I just accepted one other answer on StackOverflow and it is having some kind of time limit before I can accept another answer as true answer to my query. Hang on buddy!!!